# build definition from vsts returning zero

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

I have two build definitions in my project but its returning zero build definition. Below is my code get the build definitions. Can anyone help?

```
 // Get a reference to a build service
        IBuildServer buildserver = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        IBuildDefinition[] buildDefinitions = buildserver.QueryBuildDefinitions(project);
        foreach (IBuildDefinition buildDefinition in buildDefinitions)
        {
            string buildDefinitionName = buildDefinition.Name;

            Console.WriteLine(buildDefinitionName);
            Console.WriteLine(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What version of TFS? What kind of builds (XAML or 2015/VSTeam)? What are you passing into the `project` argument of `QueryBuildDefinitions`?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing wrong with your code. I have tested with your code and get XAML build definitions successfully. Just make sure you specify the correct **team project** to QueryBuildDefinitions(String).
2. .Net API can only get XAML build definitions. If you use new build definitions, you are not able to get the build definitions from a .net api.
3. It's suggested use REST API to get Build Definitions. REST API can get both XAML build definitions and new build definitions.

[REST API to get a list of build definitions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions):

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version={version}[&name={string}][&type={string}]
```